# Use Pathlib with PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pathlib

Since Pathlib is the clean way for Path operations for Python 3, I am wondering if it is possible to use a `Path()` straight forward with PyQt5. The biggest issue I have are the FileDialogs:

```py
mydefaultPath = Path('D:/mypath/')

target = Path(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory( # << This is part one of the issue
    self,
    'FileDialogTitle',
    str(mydefaultPath), # << This is part two of the issue 
    QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog.DontResolveSymlinks))
```

As you can see I marked two lines which includes the problems I have. First I need to get the string for the FileDialog and afterwards I need to turn the result of the FileDialog into a Path instance.

Is it possible to let PyQt work directly with Paths?

As extension I also have this problem with many other PyQt-class instances liek `QImage` with the methods `save` and `load`.

Comment: Qt does not accept `Path` objects, so you have to convert them to strings. Consider that the QFileDialog static methods for files always return a tuple: `(file path[s], selected filter)`, so you need to build Path() using the first value. Also consider that you could use QFile and QFileInfo instead of Path, which is the more standardized (and cross-platform-safe) way of dealing with file paths in Qt.

Comment: So I thought Path from pathlib is the cross-plattform-safe method.

Comment: Another thing what I like about Path are the many methods an attributes which lets me split the path much easier than os.path it allows.

Comment: Path is cross-platform, but QFile, QDir and QFileInfo are better integrated with Qt. You can obviously use pathlib, but I suggest you to read more about the Qt classes anyway, as they also provide useful methods.

Comment: Does QFile has a method to return the parent directory?

Comment: No, because QFile is usually used for direct RW access, you might want to use QFileInfo (with the QFile as argument constructor). Look for the documentation of those classes.